How to find the tec data?
I want to lstm model with inputs are sequence vectors consisting of TEC, magnetic activity index
(ap)  and solar radio flux at 10.7 cm (F107).
TEC index compose the input vector with dimension 33.
TEC is collected by the Center for Orbit Determination in Europe (CODE) Grid Ionospheric Model
(GIM) with the time resolution of an hour.
F107 is provided by National Geophysical Data Center of National
Oceanic and atmospheric administration (NOAA) with the
time resolution of one day.
(ftp://ftp.ngdc.noaa.gov/) ap
index is provided by World Data Center for Geomagnetism,
Kyoto with time resolution of 3 hours. (http://wdc.kugi.kyoto-u.ac.jp/index.html)
The dataset is
collected from Jan. 1, 1999 to Sept. 1, 2016.
But I can't able to find the data of tec, ap, f107 from above mentioned sources. Anybody help me how to find the data of three vectors? Can you provide any other sources of these data?

Your question does not seem to be about data science, but about finding something on the internet.

My apologies for sounding harsh. I tried to be clear about my point. I know that "something" is in your case a dataset and that this is included in some data science task, but the question itself is not about data science.

@Broele you're all expert here on data science, so experts maybe help me to find that data sources. For example people ask question to find good data science books although it's not data science question but some people asks it to get good guide.

You might ask over at the OpenData SE (though I'm not sure if it fits there either).
